# What's the difference between the parameters got by read and $1

Tags: linux, bash, macos

```
echo -n "*.xcodeproj directory: ";
read fileDirectory;
echo -n $fileDirectory;
fileExtension="pbxproj";
find $fileDirectory -name "*.${fileExtension}";
```

It shows "find: XXXX"(fileDirectory) no such file or directory

However if I replace `read fileDirectory` by

```
fileDirectory=$1
```

It works.

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1 is the first argument passed to bash script or to a function inside the script

for example:

```
  mybashfunction /dirtofind
```

inside the function if you write:

```
echo "$1"
```

It should print:

```
/dirtofind
```

Edit 1:

You must place the shebang in the beginning of you file

```
~$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "*.xcodeproj directory: ";
read fileDirectory;
echo -n $fileDirectory;
fileExtension="pbxproj";
find "$fileDirectory" -name "*.${fileExtension}";

~$ chmod +x a.sh
~$ ./a.sh 
*.xcodeproj directory: /home
/home/home/leonardo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/qbs/share/qbs/examples/cocoa-touch-application/CocoaTouchApplication.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
/home/leonardo/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/qbs/share/qbs/examples/cocoa-application/CocoaApplication.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
:~$
```

Works like charm here. Place the shebang

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Edit 2

Yes you can use eval. Your script will be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo -n "*.xcodeproj directory: ";
read fileDirectory;
echo -n $fileDirectory;
fileExtension="pbxproj";
eval fileDirectory=$fileDirectory
find "$fileDirectory" -name "*.${fileExtension}";
```

Comment: Thank you, but why I can't use the fileDirectory captured by `read` in `find`?

Comment: Try like this find "$fileDirectory"

Comment: I just found that "~" cannot be interpreted as /Users/XXX in the parameter captured by `read`. So is there any way to correct it, or I need to replace "~" manually?

Answer (score 1):

`read` reads data from STDIN (by default), not from positional parameters (arguments).

As you are passing the data as first argument (`$1`) to the script, `read` would not catch it; it would catch the input you are providing interactively.

Just to note, you should quote your variable expansions to avoid word splitting and pathname expansion; these are unwanted in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for your notes, but what makes the difference in using them in `find` when both of them seems correct after being printed?